# Produce 6 different number by only use "randi" and some loops

Tags: matlab

I want to only use "randi" this function to produce the 6 different number randomly in matlab ,and the range of these 6 number is  1 ~ 12.

```
number=randi([1,12],1,6)
c=0;
        for n=1:6%when "n" is 1 to 6
            while c <= 6  %while c is less equal than 6,do the program below  
                  c = c + 1; %c=c+1
                  if number(n) == number(c) %when the nth element is equal to cth element
                     number(n) = randi(12); %produce a random integer in the nth element
                     c = 0; %the reason why i set c=0 again is because i want to check again whether  the new random integer is the same as cth element or not
                  end
            end
        end   
final_number=number
```

but the result still show me like

1 "2" 6 11 "2" 3

5 "8" "8" 12 3 1

How do i improve my code to produce 6 different numbers.i don't want to always rely on the convenient matlab instruction too much,so my tags will also write c.hoping someone can help me to improve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to reproduce `randsample` (or `randperm`), why not just reproduce the algorithm MATLAB uses? (As far as we can tell...)

This is the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). If you have a vector `v`, each iteration selects a random, previously unused element and puts it at the end of the unselected elements. If you do `k` iterations, the last `k` elements of the list are your random sample. If `k` equals the number of elements in `v`, you've shuffled the entire array.

```
function sample = fisher_yates_sample(v, k)
   % Select k random elements without replacement from vector v
   % if k == numel(v), this is simply a fisher-yates shuffle
   for n = 0:k-1
      randnum = randi(numel(v)-n);   % choose from unused values
      % swap elements v(end-n) and v(randnum)
      v([end-n, randnum]) = v([randnum, end-n]);
   end
   sample = v(end-k+1:end);
end
```

Unlike MATLAB's version, mine requires a vector as input, so to get 6 random values in the range `1:12` you'd call the function like this:

```
>> fisher_yates_sample(1:12,6)
ans =

    5   11    6   10    8    4
```

Comment: Good answer. Weird to see the shuffling starting at the end, but I guess it makes sense with MATLAB.

Comment: @CrisLuengo It's done that way in other languages too, simply because it's more intuitive to have the random indices generated from a range of `0..n` (or `1..n`) rather than having to add in increasing offset on each iteration. This is the way it's described in the Wikipedia link under [The modern algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm).

Comment: what does this line mean  v([end-n, randnum]) = v([randnum, end-n]); what is end-n?

Comment: finally,someone didn't use the randperm to improve this problem

Comment: Hummmm. I’ve always thought of it as swapping (0-indexed) n and n+randnum. So that the first n elements are a random selection. But I’ve never implemented it myself. :)

Comment: @蕭仰恩 That line swaps two elements in the array. It’s a bit cryptic MATLAB syntax, but the most efficient way to swap.

Comment: oh  so this line means  Shuffle cards for k times

Answer (score 1):

Since you're re-selecting single random numbers, when there is one occuring multiple times, why not just re-selecting all numbers at once?

```
% Initial selecting of random numbers.
number = randi([1, 12], 1, 6)

% While the amount of unique elements in numbers is less than 6:
while (numel(unique(number)) < 6)

  % Re-select random numbers.
  number = randi([1, 12], 1, 6)

end
```

And since you wrote, you specifically want to use the `randi` method, I guess there is a reason, you don't want to use `randperm(12, 6)`!?

Comment: yes,the reason is i can use the randperm in matlab,but i cannot use this function in other program.i don't want to say i can just write the random 6 different numbers in matlab,because i can just use the "randperm" to finish it

Comment: so how should i improve the code?can you show me?By the way,does  "unique" this function can be used in the other program,like c?

Comment: Nearly every method can be implemented in nearly every programming language. You specifically asked for a solution using Matlab. Any porting to other languages would be your part.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [`randperm`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html). It produces a random permutation of a range of integers, so that if you select the first `k` numbers, you are sure that you get `k` unique integers in the range [1;n].

In your case, simply call:

```
randperm(12,6)
```

Comment: I know this simple function can just produce what i want,but i don't want to use this function